# reshaping a pandas data frame while doing a merge

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` *(`df`)* with some Meta data, where there is an `ID`, `Column` and `Value` which I would like to combine with another `df`  for example:

```
df_map = pd.DataFrame({"ID" : [3, 7, 17], "Column" : ["A1", "B7", "C17"], 
                       "Value" : ["ValA1", "ValB7", "ValC17"]})
```

I would like to *combine*  the above (for want of a better word) with the following `df`, where the columns names match that of the row entries in the `Column` above, and the row values in the below `df` match that of the `ID` row values above.

```
df_main = pd.DataFrame({"A1" : [3, 6], "A5" : [5, 10], "B7" : [7, 14] , 
                        "C17" : [17, 34], "C19" : [19, 38] })
```

Therefore I would like to *merge* these to `df's` in such a way that I reshape it based the `Value` columns by adding them as additional dimensions where the `ID's` match, i.e. `df_result = combine(df_map, df_main)`

**Where I basically expect a result as per below**

```
df_result = pd.DataFrame({"A1" : [3, 6], "A5" : [5, 10], "B7" : [7, 14] ,
                          "C17" : [17, 34], "C19" : [19, 38], "Value A1" : ["ValA1", None],
                         "Value B7" : ["ValB7", None], "Value C17" : ["ValC17", None ]})

Out[30]:
   A1  A5  B7  C17  C19 Value A1 Value B7 Value C17
0   3   5   7   17   19    ValA1    ValB7    ValC17
1   6  10  14   34   38     None     None      None
```

*Not sure the best way to do this in `pandas` ?*

Comment: There is typo in `["A1", "B7", "C17"]` ? Maybe correct is `["A3", "B7", "C17"]`

Comment: Why is the column `A1` in `df_map` mapped to column `A3` of `df_main`?

Comment: Ah sorry was a typo, thanks @Jezrael, fixed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with converted `index` to column for avoid lost in [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join, then reshape back by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), remove only missing columns by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and last flatten `MultiIndex` with `map`:

```
df = (df_main.reset_index()
             .melt('index',var_name='Column', value_name='ID')
             .merge(df_map, how='left')
             .set_index(['index', 'Column'])
             .unstack()
             .rename_axis(None)
             .dropna(how='all', axis=1))
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
print (df)
   ID_A1  ID_A5  ID_B7  ID_C17  ID_C19 Value_A1 Value_B7 Value_C17
0      3      5      7      17      19    ValA1    ValB7    ValC17
1      6     10     14      34      38      NaN      NaN       NaN
```

Comment: would it be Value_A3...not Value-A1?

Comment: @lostCode - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58117027/reshaping-a-pandas-data-frame-while-doing-a-merge/58117177?noredirect=1#comment102623558_58117027

Comment: @lostcode you right in sense, in the output changed to `Value A1`  to align the inputs

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution with [Series.map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and [pandas.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df2=pd.concat([df_main.T[key].map(df_map.set_index('ID')['Value']) for key in df_main.index.tolist()],axis=1).T.add_prefix('Value_')
df_main=pd.concat([df_main,df2],axis=1)
df_main.dropna(how='all',axis=1,inplace=True)
print(df_main)

   A3  A5  B7  C17  C19 Value_A3 Value_B7 Value_C17
0   3   5   7   17   19    ValA1    ValB7    ValC17
1   6  10  14   34   38      NaN      NaN       NaN
```